# sign In with Google account option in google App Engine web application

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, google-app-engine

I have a web application made using Java servlets and jsp with Eclipse up and running on GAE. I would like to add an option of logging in using Google account. I have read through some documentations but am unable to figure it out. Need immediate help with the same.
I am planning to integrate the option on my index.jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this guide from the official Google documentation:
[java-gettingstarted-ui_and_code](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code).

It contains a **jsp** code snippet with login/logout example:

```
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>

<%
  UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
  User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
  if (user != null) {
    pageContext.setAttribute("user", user);
%>

<p>Hello, ${fn:escapeXml(user.nickname)}! (You can
  <a href="<%= userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">sign out</a>.)
</p>
<%
} else {
%>
<p>Hello!
  <a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI()) %>">Sign in</a>
  to include your name with greetings you post.</p>
<%
    }
%>
```